# Adding a class to last post in the_date

Tags: date-time

I'm using `<?php the_date('l jS F Y','<h2>','</h2>'); ?>` inside the loop in order to group/sort posts by date. This all works great but I would like to add a different class to the last post for each date, effectively seperating each date section.

Does anybody know how to do this please? I can't seem to find anything! Many thanks, S.

Code below:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_date('l jS F Y','<h2>','</h2>'); ?>   
<hr />   
<div class="post">                  
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>                                     
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>             
</div> <?php endwhile; ?> <hr class="btm" /> //want this to appear at the end of each date/section
```

Updated code based on Bainternet's answer below:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            $curent_date = $post->post_date;
            $curent_date = substr($curent_date,0,strpos($curent_date," "));
            $next_post = get_adjacent_post(false,'',false) ;
            if (!$next_post == ''){
            $next_date = $next_post->post_date;
            $next_date = substr($next_date,0,strpos($next_date," "));
            if ($next_date != $curent_date){
            $hrbtm = '<hr class="btm" />';
            echo $hrbtm;
                }
            } else {
            $hrbtm = '';
            }
            ?>      
            <?php the_date('l jS F Y','<h2>','</h2>'); ?>
```

Then I echo `$hrbtm` just before the `endwhile`:

```
<?php echo $hrbtm; ?> <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please show your loop/code.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6346/order-posts-by-date-like-craigslist One note: it'll be a lot easier for you to style the __first__ post in each than the last one. Can you work with that?

Comment: Thanks goldenapples - I did see that post before, but I had already got that stage working with the `<?php the_date(); ?>`. I'm afraid it is definetly the last post that I need to add the class to : ( Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible, you can get the next post date to compare using [get_adjacent_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) function

change your code to this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

//hold current date
$curent_date = $post->post_date;
//fix the format to YYYY-MM-DD
$curent_date = substr($curent_date,0,strpos($curent_date," "));
$next_post = get_adjacent_post(false,'',false) ;
if (!$next_post == ''){
    //get next post's date
    $next_date = $next_post->post_date;
    //fix the format to YYYY-MM-DD
    $next_date = substr($next_date,0,strpos($next_date," "));
    if ($next_date != $curent_date){//last post of the date
        the_date('l jS F Y','<h2 class="lats-of-date>','</h2>');
    }
}else{
 the_date('l jS F Y','<h2>','</h2>'); 
}
?>
<hr />   
<div class="post">                  
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>                                     
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>             
</div> <?php endwhile; ?> <hr class="btm" />
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code - I did have to amend it slightly to do what I required, but it now works perfectly! Thank you. (Updated code added to original question)

Comment: @ss888 Then mark this question as answered.